# Aws Lambda Java for storing Image in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make a lambda function which will store the image in S3 bucket using Java .

The issue is my whenever I am invoking the Lambda using Http API, it gives me Internal server error. I have tried to use simple code to upload the text file in s3 bucket as well However it is not working.
I have set up a IAM role for this Lambda with following permissions:-

1. LambdaBasicExecution
2. S3 full Access
3. CloudWatch Logs

However my Lambda Function is not able to trigger the S3 bucket.
It seems that there is some issue with the configuration.
`

Comment: Do I need to pass AWS credentials in Lambda Function or I need to use Presigned Url ?

Comment: When working with the AWS Java SDK in a Lambda function -- you create an IAM role with permissions to access the services you want to invoke. For your use case, the IAM role has to have permission to use S3. Then you can use the S3 Java API and all its operations from a Lambda function. The when you deploy the Lambda function -- make sure that you reference that IAM role. No need for creds in a Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Answering if anyone face this issue like I faced:-

The issue was with Maven Dependency. I was using S3 SDK version which was picking up mismatch Object versions for other Aws SDKs and it was giving Internal Server Error.

Comment: All Maven POM files for using the AWS SDKs for Java V2 (the recommended version to use) are part of the Github repo.  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2